# Spark 2.1: Out of Memory when Writing DataFrame to parquet file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a DataFrame (approx 14 million rows) to a local parquet file, but I keep running out of memory doing so. I have a big map `val myMap : Map[String,Seq[Double]]` and use this map in a `udf` for a very large DataFrame via `val newDF = df.withColumn("stuff",udfWithMap)`. I have 128G of RAM available and after persisting the DataFrame to DISK_ONLY and performing `df.show`, I still have around 100G of RAM left. However, when I try `df.write.parquet`, the amount of memory Spark needs skyrockets and I run out of memory. I have also tried broadcasting `myMap`, but doing so doesn't seem to have any effect on memory. What is the problem?

This is a sample of my code:

```
scala> type LookupMapSeq = (String, Seq[Double])

scala> val myMap = sc.objectFile[LookupMapSeq]("file:///data/dir/myMap").collectAsMap()

/* myMap.size is about 150,000 and each Seq[String] is of size 200 */

scala> val combineudf = functions.udf[Seq[Double], Seq[String]] { v1 =>
  val wordVec = v1.map(y => myMap.getOrElse(y, Seq.fill(200)(0.0)))
  wordVec.foldLeft(Seq.fill(200)(0.0)) { case (acc, list) =>
    acc.zipWithIndex.map { case (value, i) => value + list(i) }
  }
}

scala> import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

scala> val df6 = df3.withColumn("sum", combineudf(df3("filtered"))).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

scala> df6.show

+--------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------
-+
|    pmid|            filtered|            TFIDFvec|                 sum|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|25393341|[retreatment, rec...|[0.0, 26.21009534...|[4.34963607663623...|
|25394466|[lactate, dehydro...|[21.3762879413052...|[-17.550128685500...|
|25394717|[aim, study, inve...|[3.11641169932197...|[-54.981726214632...|    

scala> df6.write.parquet("file:///data/dir/df6")

/* This results in out of memory */
```